# How can you style imported XML with XSL in Word?

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word

I have an XML file whose contents I need to import into a Microsoft Word 2007 document.

I have an XSL file that constructs a WordprocessingML table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> 

<w:style w:type="table" w:styleId="TableStyle">
    <w:name w:val="Table Style"/>
    <w:tblPr>
        <w:tblBorders>
            <w:insideH w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
        </w:tblBorders>
    </w:tblPr>
</w:style>  

<xsl:template match="list">

    <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">
        <xsl:text>progid="Word.Document"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>

    <w:tbl>
        <w:tblPr>
            <w:tblStyle w:val="TableStyle"/>
        </w:tblPr>
        <w:tblGrid>
            <w:gridCol w:w="100" />
            <w:gridCol w:w="200" />
            <w:gridCol w:w="1024" />
        </w:tblGrid>
        <w:tr>
            <w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>ID</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>
            <w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>Description</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>   
        </w:tr> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item">
            <xsl:sort select="id" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </w:tbl>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="items/item">
    <w:tr>
        <w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>
            <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
        </w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>
        <w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>
            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        </w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>
    </w:tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I use the Word INCLUDETEXT field to import the XML file and apply the transformation:

```
{INCLUDETEXT  "E:\\Spinner\\Documents\\data.xml" \t "E:\\Spinner\\Documents\\stylesheet.xsl"}
```

This works fine as far as actually importing the data is concerned - a basic table is displayed with the data I need.

The table, however, is devoid of any formatting - no borders, no gridlines, no shading, etc. Word ignores the column widths I specified in my XSL file (`<w:gridCol w:w="100" />`, etc.) and sets its own.

I need to format it using (preferably) a style already present in the document, such as "Table Grid", or "Medium Shading 1 - Accent 3." However, I can't get Word to actually apply the style, either for an already-present-in-Word-document style (`<w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/>`), or a newly-defined-in-XSL-file style (`<w:tblStyle w:val="TableStyle"/>`).

Has anyone any pointers?

Comment: If you can't get that to work, try an altChunk?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into altChunk, but from my initial investigation it looks more complex than I need, and probably too complex for my users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something more like this, but I think you may need to adjust the column widths (possibly to take account of the cell borders)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> 

<xsl:template match="list">
  <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">
  <xsl:text>progid="Word.Document"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:processing-instruction>
  <w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml"  w:macrosPresent="no" w:embeddedObjPresent="no" 
w:ocxPresent="no" xml:space="preserve">
    <w:styles>
      <w:style w:type="table" w:styleId="TableStyle">
        <w:name w:val="Table Style"/>
        <w:tblPr>
          <w:tblBorders>
             <w:insideH w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
          </w:tblBorders>
        </w:tblPr>
      </w:style>
    </w:styles>
    <w:body>
      <w:tbl>
        <w:tblPr>
            <w:tblStyle w:val="TableStyle"/>
        </w:tblPr>
        <w:tblGrid>
            <w:gridCol w:w="100" />
            <w:gridCol w:w="1024" />
        </w:tblGrid>
        <w:tr>
            <w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>ID</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>
            <w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>Description</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>   
        </w:tr> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item">
            <xsl:sort select="id" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </w:tbl>
    </w:body>
  </w:wordDocument>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="items/item">
    <w:tr>
        <w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>
            <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
        </w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>
        <w:tc><w:p><w:r><w:t>
            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        </w:t></w:r></w:p></w:tc>
    </w:tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, looking at your code I see I was missing wrapping various parts in `<w:wordDocument>`, `<w:styles>`, and `<w:body>` tags.